# Android Emulator doesn't match phone

Tags: android

I have a layout with graphics drawn in custom Views using the Canvas drawing primitives, plus a TextView and 2 buttons.    The emulator is set to the same pixel width as the phone (400 pixels) and the 2D graphics are specified in pixel dimensions.

[image: Here's a picture.]    (Emulator on the left, phone on the right.)

Note the the graphics match.  (the actual content of the graphics are different because the data is different )   **But the TextView and buttons are radically different.**  Here's the XML -

```
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#303080"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
   <TextView android:id="@+id/eventSummary" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:background="#202090"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:minLines="4" 
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="text" />
   <Button android:id="@+id/PrevButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="prevButtonHandler"
    android:text="&lt;"
   />
   <Button android:id="@+id/NextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:onClick="nextButtonHandler"
    android:text="&gt;"
   /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

... I've tried specifying the TextView width using SP's and DP's.    Why is there such a big difference and how can I get the Emulator and phone to match?  (FWIW the phone is an HTC Droid Incredible).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not all emulators are perfect. Perhaps submit this as a bug report to the makers of the emulator.

Comment: It's just the regular android emulator.  Besides, the 2D graphics match, and the TextView width (250) looks more correct on the emulator than the Phone.    I need to understand why there's such a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `layout_width` in `dp` in the `LinearLayout`, then using `android:layout_weight="1"` in the `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#303080"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    <TextView android:id="@+id/eventSummary" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#202090"    
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minLines="4" 
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="text" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/PrevButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="prevButtonHandler"
        android:text="&lt;"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/NextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="nextButtonHandler"
        android:text="&gt;"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This produced essentially the same result as the original.

Comment: @Peter Nelson so the xml I suggested produced the same result as the original xml in both the emulator *and* the device?

Comment: Yes.  But I've solved my problem by using a TableLayout instead of a LinearLayout.   This had the additional advantage that I could do it without having to code any literal widths - I could keep everything well behaved with weighting alone.

Comment: @Peter Nelson my next suggestion would have been to use `layout_weight` alone with no `dp` values to space the elements on the screen.  Would have required an additional `LinearLayout` though.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but its probably because of pixel density.  Check out this link and see if it helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html